# Join without creating duplicate records

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables product table and category table. Below is how the category table looks-

```
Product_ID     Category             sub-category     
   123         Furniture             Bookcases             
   123         Furniture             Chairs                
   456         Office supplies       Labels                
   456         Office supplies       Binders               
   456         Office supplies       Binders
```

Product table looks like below-

```
Product_ID   Quantities_sold
   123           300
   456           400
```

when I inner join the product and category table I see many duplicates because of the different sub-categories like below-

```
Product_ID     Category             sub-category     Quantities_sold
   123         Furniture             Bookcases             300
   123         Furniture             Chairs                300
   456         Office supplies       Labels                400
   456         Office supplies       Binders               400
   456         Office supplies       Binders               400
```

The expected result would be something like-

```
Product_ID     Category             sub-category     Quantities_sold
   123         Furniture             Bookcases             300
                                     Chairs                
   456         Office supplies       Labels                400
                                     Binders
```

Is there a way to have all sub-categories but without duplicate records?

Note- I have a huge dataset having millions of records, 26 categories, and 135 sub-categories.

Comment: Please add the expected result.

Comment: @TheImpaler I edited the question with the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Product_ID, Category, SubCategories, Quantities_sold
FROM `project.dataset.product` p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Product_ID, Category, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT SubCategory ) SubCategories
  FROM `project.dataset.category`
  GROUP BY Product_ID, Category
) c
USING (Product_ID)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row Product_ID  Category        SubCategories       Quantities_sold  
1   123         Furniture       Bookcases,Chairs    300  
2   456         Office supplies Labels,Binders      400
```

or use ARRAY_AGG instead of STRING_AGG to get subcategories as array as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Product_ID, Category, SubCategories, Quantities_sold
FROM `project.dataset.product` p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT Product_ID, Category, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT SubCategory ) SubCategories
  FROM `project.dataset.category`
  GROUP BY Product_ID, Category
) c
USING (Product_ID)
```

in this case result will be as below

```
Row Product_ID  Category        SubCategories   Quantities_sold  
1   123         Furniture       Bookcases       300  
                                Chairs       
2   456         Office supplies Labels          400  
                                Binders
```

Comment: I edited the question with the expected result. Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: sure, just use `ARRAY_AGG` instead of `STRING_AGG`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` And It Won't Show You Duplicate Records, Like This:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Category, sub-category, Quantities_sold
FROM product, category
INNER JOIN category ON category.Product_ID = product.Product_ID
```